# Ansible parse file and read into variables

Tags: ansible

I have a file I have to read from, that is written like this:  (it cannot be changed)

```
user_passwords:
- { username: user1, plaintextPassword: password }
- { username: user2, plaintextPassword: password }
```

I need to read the file, then assign the values above to the following variables and write them to a file.
I'm not sure how to loop through this in ansible.

Variables and values I need to write:
user1: user1
user1password: password
user2: user2
user2password: password

Here is what I've tried:

```
- name: Read file 
  include_vars:
     file: myfile
     
- name: assign variables 
    user1:  {{ username.1 }}
    user1password {{ plaintextPassword.1 }}
    user2:  {{ username.2 }}
    user2password:  {{ plaintextPassword.2 }}
  loop:  user_passwords
```

but this is not giving me any results. Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your case you do not need to loop. Access the respective values by positions in the list of user_passwords

```
- name: Read file 
  include_vars:
     file: myfile
     
- name: assign variables 
    user1:  {{ user_passwords[0]['username'] }}
    user1password {{ user_passwords[0]['plaintextPassword'] }}
    user2:  {{ user_passwords[1]['username'] }}
    user2password:  {{ user_passwords[1][' plaintextPassword'] }}
```

Comment: I do not get that running at all, there are several syntax errors reported.